# sending a GET request from a banner

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, get

I have to build a banner where people fill a form with their name and email send when they click, we send the data in order to send them back a brochure instantly.

I am not a dev, so it is a little bit confusing for me and I hope my explanations will be clear enough.

Apparently, the website only accept POST request but we cannot send like that from the banner due to crossdomain issue. So the request has to be send as a GET.
We found this website which does the conversion:
http://get-to-post.nickj.org/

for the purpose of the test, everything is hardcoded. When we test, this url:

http://get-to-post.nickj.org/?http://www.vikingrivercruises.co.uk/Forms/SaveRequestBrochures?InquiryReason[0]=2351&InquiryMessage[0]=UK+River+Brochure+Download&InquiryType[0]=Brochure-d&InquiryReason[1]=1450&InquiryMessage[1]=UK+Brochure+Requests+%28from+web%29&InquiryType[1]=Brochure&BrochureCode=UKBR15&SelectedBrochuresDeliverability=UKBR15+mail-yes+ebrochure-yes&selectedBrochures=UKBR15&Title=Mr.&FirstName=Andrew&LastName=Davies&EmailAddress=nicom21a%40gmail.com&PhoneNumberString=098921313132312&Country=United+Kingdom&OtherCountry=&Address1=&Address2=&Address3=&City=&State=&OtherState=&Zip=&EmailMeSpecialOffers=true&FriendTitle=&FriendFirstName=&FriendLastName=&FriendEmailAddress=&RedirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vikingrivercruises.co.uk%2Fbrochures%2Frivers-brochure-thank-you.html

and copy past it in the browser, it works perfectly and we receive a brochure instantly, but when I try to replicate it from the banner it doesn't work.
Here is my code, many thanks

```
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

requestVars.link = 'InquiryReason[0]=2351&InquiryMessage[0]=UK+River+Brochure+Download&InquiryType[0]=Brochure-d&InquiryReason[1]=1450&InquiryMessage[1]=UK+Brochure+Requests+%28from+web%29&InquiryType[1]=Brochure&BrochureCode=UKBR15&SelectedBrochuresDeliverability=UKBR15+mail-yes+ebrochure-yes&selectedBrochures=UKBR15&Title=Mr.&FirstName=Andrew&LastName=Davies&EmailAddress=nicom21a%40gmail.com&PhoneNumberString=098921313132312&Country=United+Kingdom&OtherCountry=&Address1=&Address2=&Address3=&City=&State=&OtherState=&Zip=&EmailMeSpecialOffers=true&FriendTitle=&FriendFirstName=&FriendLastName=&FriendEmailAddress=&RedirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vikingrivercruises.co.uk%2Fbrochures%2Frivers-brochure-thank-you.html'

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = 'http://get-to-post.nickj.org/?http://www.vikingrivercruises.co.uk/Forms/SaveRequestBrochures';
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
request.data = requestVars;

for (var prop:String in requestVars) {
trace("Sent " + prop + " as: " + requestVars[prop]);
}

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

I also tried like that

```
request.url = 'http://get-to-post.nickj.org/?http://www.vikingrivercruises.co.uk/Forms/SaveRequestBrochures?';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are many points in your case that should be clarified :

- If you want send a URL request to a server, but ignores any response, and I think this is your case because you can't get response, It's better to use **[`sendToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#sendToURL%28%29)** instead of [`URLLoader.load()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29).
- If you test your swf on line, you will get a security error because the used site(http://get-to-post.nickj.org/) doesn't have a crossdomain.xml file to get authorization to execute the URL : http://get-to-post.nickj.org/?http://www.example.com/?param=value.
- Even when you execute your `sendToURL` successfully, you have another problem because the site that you have mentioned, which convert `GET` request to a `POST` one, will not do the job because it's creating a page with a `POST` form with your data and submitting it when the page is loaded which is never fired with flash.

So, I think it's better to see the crossdomain problem with your target site (vikingrivercruises) to give you authorization to send `POST` data. And if It's always impossible, try to set another URL (site) that get your `GET` data and send it via `curl`, for example, to your destination.